# Passing a variable to its parent function in PHP?

Tags: php, function, variables, return-value

I have a function w/in a function, and I need the inner function to make it's variables available in a scope of parent function, e.g.:

```
function sayMyName(){
    getName(); // inner function generates $name value

    echo $name; // use $name
}

sayMyName();
```

I could easily just globalize things w/in both functions... But my situation is far more complicated and handles more variables and globalizing each one is a bit tedious.

Thanks.

PS
i noticed a lot of "return" suggestions. sorry i wasnt clear , i need to return more variables.. not a simple return. thanks guys

Comment: If you need to access a variable in such a way, most likely, your design is flawed.  If such a need really exist, think about returning that variable from a function or (worse solution) using by-reference parameters.

Comment: Why are you not working object oriented with classes and such?

Comment: Fudging hell, is it really that difficult to see that this person is most likely still learning how PHP works? Stop showering him with design and OO stuff -- you're not impressing or helping anybody.

Comment: haha i know im gona get OOP comments here.. thanks for the defense Arno, but to be honest i've been coding php for over 10 years already.. and yes i do OOP as well.. unfortunately, i didnt have formal training, everything i just picked up along the way. reading tutorials etc..i've become pretty good but i do have questions from time to time. 

i promised myself not to answer any more WHY NOT OOP question.. unlike others using other libraries and frameworks, i actually built my own libraries of functions and classes, MY WAY..

Comment: anyway all i really needed to know is if this was possible by some way , technique or work around or even in the new versions of PHP (ive not been updated w/ the latest) .. that's all. if not then i have tons of other ways to achieve what i want.. 

and yes I do use OOP, but when i need to.. like for my CRUD requirements .. but i personally dont believe / agree w/ the 100% OOP concept , specially for lots of simple stuffs i dont find .. its d same argument as WHY PUT CSS STYLING in your DIV element directly, when you can separate that in CSS block/file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use `$_GLOBALS`, but it`s a "bad practice". So,

---

***1: Use [`return`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php):***

```
<?php
function getName(){
    $name = 'Smith';

    return $name;
}

function sayMyName(){
    $name = getName();

    echo $name;
}

sayMyName();
?>
```

Shows:

```
Smith
```

---

***2: Use [`references`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php):***

```
<?php
function getName(&$name){
    $name = 'Smith';
}

function sayMyName(){
    getName($name);

    echo $name;
}

sayMyName();
?>
```

Shows:

```
Smith
```

---

***3: Return [`array`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) for multiple variables:***

```
<?php
function getName(){
    $surname = 'Smith';
    $name    = 'John';

    return array($surname, $name);
}

function sayMyName(){
    list($surname, $name) = getName();

    echo $name, ' ', $surname;
}

sayMyName();
?>
```

Shows:

```
John Smith
```

---

***4. Return custom [`object`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php) for multiple variables:***

```
<?php
function getName(){
    $surname = 'Smith';
    $name    = 'John';

    $buffer = new stdClass();

    $buffer->name    = $name;
    $buffer->surname = $surname;

    return $buffer;
}

function sayMyName(){
    $obj = getName();

    echo $obj->name, ' ', $obj->surname;
}

sayMyName();
?>
```

Shows:

```
John Smith
```

---

***5. Use [`anonymous function`](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) with `use` statement and `references`:***

```
<?php
function sayMyName(){
    $surname = $name = 'Unknown';

    $temp = function() use (&$name, &$surname){
        $surname = 'Smith';
        $name    = 'John';
    };

    $temp();

    echo $name, ' ', $surname;
}

sayMyName();
?>
```

Shows:

```
John Smith
```

Comment: Wow thanks man.. bunch of ideas there .. i think ill take the returning array route and just parse that in the parent function

Comment: **@BrownChiLD**, probably never thinking myself about it. :) Thanx to you. And yes, I share the concept you have written above.

Answer (score 3):

do this

```
function sayMyName(){
    $name = getName(); // inner function generates $name value

    echo $name; // results will be returned
}

sayMyName();
```

I hope your inner function is returning name like this

```
function getName(){
    return $name;
}
```

then it will work

Comment: thanks man, that works but i needed to send multiple vars back to the parent function, not just 1.. unless return $name,$age,$etc can work lolz.

Comment: In that case create an array and put key value pairs. Return the array and then access those values using the returned array.

Answer (score 3):

This is what the [object oriented programming](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) was designed for. If many functions should share variables, it is probably best to encapsulate them to class like this:

```php
class WhateverDescibestYourViewOfTheWorld {
    protected $name;

    function __construct( $name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    function GetName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    function SayName()
    {
        echo $this->name;
    }
}

// And use it:
$o = new WhateverDescibestYourViewOfTheWorld();
...
$o->SayName();
```

Or you can build class which will be just used as data container:

```php
class DataContainer {
    public $name;
    public $address;
    // ...
}

// By reference this will modify object previously created
function GetProperties( &$dataContainer) // Note that & isn't necessary since PHP5
{
    $dataContainer->name = "...";
}

$c = new DataContainer();
GetProperties($c);
```

Or you can simplify this and use array:

```php
function GetProperties( array &$dataContainer)
{
     $dataContainer['name'] = '...';
}

$data = array();
GetProperties($data);
```

Comment: Check the third comment to the question.

Comment: @ArnoSluismans yeah, you're right... I was too offensive, I've added more useful notes and examples on how to do that (still the OOP is the best solution except very rare cases).

Comment: tbh OOP in php is very rarely the best solution but each to their own ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use references

```
    $param = "aaa";
    function f(&$param)
    {
      //dostuff
      inner($param);
      echo $param;
    }
    function inner(&$inner) { //do other stuff }
```

or use return value

```
 function f() { echo inner(); } 

 function inner($param) {return $param;}
```

if you work on references, both functions will work on same variable, not on a copy

http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php

the best way would be with class

```
<?php 
class Person
{
 private $name;

 public function setName($name){ $this->name = $name;}
 public function sayName() {echo $this->name;}
}

$person = new Person();
$person->setName("Robert");
$person->sayName();
```

It's good way to make it in OOP.

Answer (score 1):

What about first assigning the return value of getName() to a variable?

```
$name = getName();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only need one variable you can do this

```
function getName(){
    // Some code
    return 'my name is XXX';
}
function sayMyName(){
     $name = getName(); // inner function generates $name value
     echo $name; // results to undefined
 }
 sayMyName();
```

Otherwise you may consider using a class : http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Answer (score 1):

That what you are thinking is wrong, however you can return an array of values. For ex:

```
function sayMyName()
{
    $result = getName(); // inner function creates an array

    echo $result['name']; 
}
```

or better an object:

```
class Results
{
    public $name;
}

function sayMyName()
{
    $result = getName(); // inner function creating an object

    echo $result->name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it as below.

```
$name = "";

function sayMyName(){
    getName(); // inner function generates $name value
    //set $name variable inside getName() function.
    echo $name; // results to undefined
}

sayMyName();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use bellow code ,it will solve your problem

```
global $var;
```

You can use it anywhere within your php span.

Comment: ...and this will also unnecessary increase the number of global scoped variables -- which is why this is not a generally recommended practice.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/12445972/2943403