# How to fill an array with a function, and use that array outside the function?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, nested-lists

I'am working in *CodeIgniter (CI)*, and trying to create a nested set of category items for a dropdown list. To create a dropdown box, in *CI* you need to `echo form_dropdown('name', $array, $selectedID)`.

Here is my function to create a nested list array:

```
$categoryData = array();
function list_categories($cats, $sub = ''){
    foreach($cats as $cat){

        //$cat['category']->id = $sub.$cat['category']->title;
        $categoryData[$cat['category']->id] = $sub.$cat['category']->title;

        if( sizeof($cat['children']) > 0 ){
            $sub2 = str_replace('&mdash;&rarr;&nbsp;', '&ndash;', $sub);
            $sub2.= '&ndash;&rarr;&nbsp;';
            list_categories($cat['children'], $sub2);
        }
    }
}
```

If I will do a `var_dump($categoryData);` just right after the `foreach` inside the `list_categories()` function, it will return the array of nested sets. So this is ok when using `var_dump()` inside the function. But I need to do this:

```
<?php
    list_categories($categories);
    var_dump($categoryData);
?>
```

And here i get an empty array, here is an output:

```
array (size=0)
  empty
```

Could someone tell me what I'am doing wrong here ?

Comment: Your function isn't returning anything. Put `$categoryData = array();` into the first line of the function, and add `return $categoryData` at the end of the function. Also, you're not assigning `list_categories()` to anything when you call it: `$categoryData = list_categories($categories);`

Comment: Even if I do at the end of the function `return $categoryData;`, it still be empty where I'am doing a `var_dump()`. Do you know why ?

Comment: @aspirinemaga , updated. Please, consider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function modifies local copy, which should be returned to global scope. What you want to achieve might be done with [`globals`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) ("bad practice"), [`return`](http://www.php.net/return) or [`references`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php).

Try to use `references`:

```
function list_categories(&$result, $cats, $sub = ''){    // <- THIS
    foreach($cats as $cat){

        //$cat['category']->id = $sub.$cat['category']->title;
        $result[$cat['category']->id] = $sub.$cat['category']->title; // <- THIS

        if( sizeof($cat['children']) > 0 ){
            $sub2 = str_replace('&mdash;&rarr;&nbsp;', '&ndash;', $sub);
            $sub2.= '&ndash;&rarr;&nbsp;';

            list_categories($result, $cat['children'], $sub2); // <- THIS
        }
    }
}

$categoryData = array();

list_categories($categoryData, $categories); // <- THIS
```

---

***UPD:*** In the end, for recusive function, references are better (as for me). Sorry for the inconvinience.

Comment: I tested it out, once you added your answer, and it output only the last array. If you relook into the foreach statement, you will notice that it goes deeper and deeper, so by creating multiarrays inside the arrays. Any idea? BTW I could test it tonight, and will give you my feedback.Thank you for your post

Comment: @aspirinemaga it's currently should be recursive. I've misread question first time.

Answer (score 0):

you should:

```
function list_categories($cats, $sub = ''){
global $categoryData;  // add this
```

If you do not, function does not see the global $categoryData and creates a local one instead. which it does not return.

Note that, minimal use of global variables is recommended for avoiding spagetthi code.

Comment: I read somewhere in `PHP security` that using `global ...` is not recommended. Isn't it applying to a function ?

Comment: @aspirinemaga it is not a security issue. It's "bad" in "wrong hands".

Comment: @aspirinemaga , also check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16054279/passing-a-variable-to-its-parent-function-in-php). It might be applied to the global scope too.