# Is it possible to define a variable in an external PHP file and use it inside a class without passing it as a parameter. if yes, how?

Tags: php

I mean a variable that will behave like PHP super global ($_POST,$_GET etc), so that once it is defined it becomes available to all scripts.

Comment: it can behave like PHP ordinal global variable as well.

Comment: It is possible, but the question is whether you really want to do that...

Comment: possible, yes; bad practice, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible if you add an index to [`$GLOBALS`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php).

Like this:

```
$GLOBALS['foo'] = 'bar';
```

`$GLOBALS` will be available in any scope.

---

Also you can just define a variable in the global scope. But to be available in functions it has to be declared in the function using the [`global`](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.scope.php) keyword.

```
$foo = 1;

function test() {
    global $foo;
    echo $foo;
}
```

Comment: Using global variables like this is generally frowned up.

Comment: Is the generally true? Can you explain why?

Comment: *General* in [software design](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1557799/164998). PHP being a dynamic language makes doing so easy. But that doesn't means its [good](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12446305/164998).

Comment: What makes your constant approach better? Btw, This post about software design that you've linked isn't a good one. If you cannot explain it with own words, then I have to assume that it is just *because other's say*. Btw, I can give you some reasons for being this a bad design. But this would just being reasons for particular situations and not in general. Sometimes it is just quite useful. As you see with `$_GET`, `$_POST`, ...

Comment: Why do you need more when the community has spoken? Look around you. The only *upvotes* on this question are comments saying that globals are *generally bad practice* and be careful how you use them. The question itself is downvoted. That should tell you something.

Comment: Note that community is not always right. Last friday I've earned 4 upvotes for a wrong regex. (corrected this of course)

Comment: hek2mgl - Your answer helped me, though not completely.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by defining variables.

```
define(MY_VAR,"MY_VALUE");
```

You can go on and on and put all of them in a php file which you include in the other php files where you need those variables. You can select those variables like this:

```
include('VARS_FILE.php');
$var = MY_VAR;
```

Comment: Constants are not the same as vars. They are read only. What if you need to change the value?

Comment: That's true, but it is a good way to use some constant vars, but why wouldn't you work with sessions?

Comment: I don't think that `$_SESSION` is the right approach to the question. What if it is a cli script?