# Netbeans php - expected eof but found }

Tags: php, netbeans, eof

I am using netbeans php 7.3 and cant seem to solve this warning 
" Expected EOF but found } "

The code is below. Its in a php file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function downloadStats($filename,$album,$type){                        
$('#downloaddiv').html('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" />');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'download.php',

<?php
    if($_GET['urltype']=='basketball'){
?>
        data: "filename=" + $filename + "&album=" + $album + "&type=" + $type + "&area=source&uploadyear=<?php echo $uploadyear;?>",
<?php
    } else {
?>
        data: "filename=" + $filename + "&album=" + $album + "&type=" + $type + "&uploadyear=<?php echo $uploadyear;?>",
<?php
    }
?>
<?php global $tag; ?> 
        success: function(msg) {
            $('#downloaddiv').html('<b title="Stat available for download. Click HERE to download."  ><?php echo $tag['view_013'];?> <?php echo $tag['view_014'];?> <a href="'+msg+'"><?php echo $tag['view_015'];?></a> <?php echo $tag['view_016'];?></b>');
        }

    });   <===  red circle/exclamation mark here
}
</script>
```

Netbeans throws up a red circle /exclamation mark on the second last  line });

The php file is 600+ lines and so to make matters simple i pasted the code section into a new file and netbeans still threw an error at the same place  });

Comment: I think you confuse netbeans with your buggy js?

Comment: Just use print/echo statements, don't use all these  ?> <?php, it makes the code unreadable

Comment: TravisO's suggestion is good. But for your current code, try changing the single quotes in your `<?php echo $tag['view_x'];?>` parts of the success function to double quotes. I'm pretty sure that will help.

Comment: @bwoebi , netbeans is the ide i am using. I am just trying to get rid of the errors / red circles.

Comment: @jonhopkins - tried the single quotes -> double quotes, the red circle is still there - same place as before, that is at });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited the code, try this now:

```
<?php
function downloadStats($filename,$album,$type){
?>                     
$('#downloaddiv').html('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" />');
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'download.php',

<?php
if($_GET['urltype']=='basketball') :
?>
    data: "filename=" + $filename + "&album=" + $album + "&type=" + $type + "&area=source&uploadyear=<?php echo $uploadyear;?>",
<?php
else :
?>
    data: "filename=" + $filename + "&album=" + $album + "&type=" + $type + "&uploadyear=<?php echo $uploadyear;?>",
<?php
endif;
global $tag; ?> 
    success: function(msg) {
        $('#downloaddiv').html('<b title="Stat available for download. Click HERE to download."  ><?php echo $tag['view_013'];?> <?php echo $tag['view_014'];?> <a href="'+msg+'"><?php echo $tag['view_015'];?></a> <?php echo $tag['view_016'];?></b>');
    }

});
<?php
}
?>


<script type="text/javascript">
<?php echo downloadStats($filename,$album,$type); ?>
</script>
```

About closing and opening php this is what I mean:

This works but is not the bestway:

```
<?php
endif;
?>
<?php
global $tag; ?>
```

This works but is much better:

```
<?php
endif;
global $tag; ?>
```

Also if posible don't use global see more info about that see this url: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12446305/1788516

**Edit**

The problem is because there is javascript and php in the same file. for more information see this http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=166694  for the bug.

Comment: Perry, Could you tell me where i missed the closing tag. Also which one did you delete?

Comment: Also i pasted your code in and it threw up 2 more red circles :)  I think i should have mentioned its javascript in a php file. I am tasked with maintaining it and documentation is scarce.

Comment: I just saw you changed it. I will take a look at it.

Comment: will retry. Thanx for the effort.

Comment: the red circles still appear at line                                                          success: function(msg) {
        $('#downloaddiv').html('<b title="Stat available for download. Click HERE to download."  ><?php echo $tag['view_013'];?> <?php echo $tag['view_014'];?> <a href="'+msg+'"><?php echo $tag['view_015'];?></a> <?php echo $tag['view_016'];?></b>');                                                              and at line
    }

Comment: The problem seems to be at                                     success: function(msg) { }

Comment: When I test the code I don't have any read circle, have you any other code above these lines? I also tried the code to see what the out will be and that is also correct

Comment: The php file is about 600+ lines and the code section in question is about lines 113-137

Comment: Lol ok. You should check the code above this there must be the problem :)

Comment: i tried creating a new php file in netbeans and pasted that code  section alone and netbeans still threw a red circle at the exact same place  });

Comment: That is strange u have the same netbeans version and it don't have that red circle. What is happing when you execute the code?

Comment: The 600+ line php file is fine....nothing seems broken...i am getting the functionality we are suposed to get. Its just the netbeans red circle error... i just want to get rid of it..

Comment: Check out this bug: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=166694 can you test the JavaScript code in a js file or a html file?

Comment: great find. At least I can breathe easy and just move on to the next bug/warning. The code section has php embedded in it, kinda hard to replace dynamically? When i remove the php tags, more red circles pop up... :) I am accepting your last comment as a virtual "answer". Thanx     for the effort.