# Variable from required document not found

Tags: php, mysqli, require

MySQLiconfig.php:

```
<?php
$MySQLi   = new mysqli('localhost','root','123','Database') or die('ERROR');
```

Other document:

```
<?php
require 'MySQLiconfig.php';

function DoAQuery($Query){
   $MySQLi->query($Query);
}
```

The error is:

```
 Undefined variable: MySQLi
```

Comment: That's because `$MySQLI` is out of [scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) in your `DoAQuery()` function.

Comment: Pass `$MySQLi` as a parameter

Comment: @Mr.Alien Was just about to edit that into my comment :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien,@vascowhite Would it be a good solution if I would write 'global $MySQLi;' inside the function?

Comment: @Entimon No, you shouldn't use `global`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12445972/476

Comment: Change your funtion signature to `DoAQuery(mysqli $MySQLi, $Query)`.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Is there a way to set the Connection parameter of a function to a default one like DoAQuery($MySQLi = new MySQli ....)?

Comment: You'd have to use `DoAQuery($Query, mysqli $MySQLi=null)` and create it from within the method if `null`, but that's horrible from the design point of view.

Answer (score -1):

You are wrong with variable scope. In the function you need to use like `global $MySQLi` or you can pass as function parameter.