# How do I use wc() in woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, oop, woocommerce

I'm working on using the `wc()` function in woocommerce. [The documentation](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/function-WC.html) says it `Returns the main instance of WC to prevent the need to use globals.`

I can't find any examples of the use of this and I would like to know how to use wc() to do some basic things. I understand that it returns the main woocommerce instance; and from that I can extract all the data I would need; but I don't know the syntax for correct use ... might it be something like?

```
$foo = WC();
$bar = $foo->cart;
echo $bar;
```

could someone please correct this.

Also I am trying to understand what the advantages of doing it this way instead of globalizing variables.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

as what the doc in your link says. 'prevent the need to use globals'. An example would be like this...

code using global.

```
global $woocommerce;
$customer_country = $woocommerce->customer->get_country();
```

code not using global

```
$customer_country = WC()->customer->get_country(); 
// some servers may not like like this... best is to use variables like $foo = WC(); then use $foo->customer->get_country()...
```

How to use WC() ? [start here](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/class-reference/)...

[why must I avoid global?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12445972/stop-using-global-in-php)

Comment: Wow a lot easier than I thought, thanks, that all makes perfect sense

Comment: Not related to the original question, but why do people always write it as `WC()` not `wc()`. Any reason?

Comment: @tfont did you mean `wc` ? It's written in lowercase in the source code.

Comment: @Fahmi Now you made me do a bit of research! And version 3.2.6 has WC() but version 3.4.0 has wc(). Documentation uses wc but their URL has WC... in a nutshell, seems like they're being used in a exchangeable matter. it doesn't matter since PHP isn't case sensitive.

https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-WC.html

Comment: interesting - i didnt know php isnt case sensitive.

Answer (score -1):

WC() is just a function that returns an instance of the woocommerce class.

1) make sure you include the reference to the file where the function is located (see how to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32288861/class-autoloader-in-wordpress-plugin/45766931#45766931)) :

```
include_once WP_PLUGIN_DIR .'/woocommerce/woocommerce.php';
```

2) once you have that you can just add a local variable pointing to the current woocommerce instance:

```
$myWC = WC();

$myWC->cart->calculate_fees();
```

Comment: It's unlikely you will need to include woocommerce.php unless you are doing something very specialized - e.g. custom ajax implemenation