# How to share MySQL connection over class in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to share a MySQL connection, with other class within PHP, which held the query to do.
So MySQL.php contains:

```
    <?php
$user = 'username';
$passowrd = 'password';
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=ip;dbname=DBName;port=3306',$user,$passowrd);
?>
```

And the php file, which I call MyLibrary.php contains:

```
    <?php
include 'DB.php';

class Manager {

    function jsonQuery() {

        $response = array ();


        $st = $conn->query ( "query");

        $response ["results"] = array ();

        foreach ( $st->fetchAll () as $row ) {

            //my stuff with the query
        }

        $response ["success"] = 1;

        echo json_encode ( $response );
    }

}

$object = new Manager();

$object->jsonQuery();

?>
```

So how can I do ?

Comment: You don't want to keep the database connection open and share it across different modules of your project. Instead you include the file that opens the database (i.e. `MySQL.php`) wherever you need database access and close it after your queries.

Comment: You can make a class for the connect that have a variable, maybe a controller, and then always extend that. Just remember to make a __construct in the controller that makes the variable to the PDO connection

Comment: I believe what you are after is something called the [singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), but could equally be done with a static class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called [dependency injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130794/what-is-dependency-injection) and it's simple to implement. You pass the parameter into your class directly when you instantiate it. This way you never implement it more than once and you share that instance across your codebase

```
class Manager {
    /** @var \PDO */
    protected $pdo;

    public function __construct(\PDO $pdo) {
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
    }

    public function jsonQuery() {
        $response = array ();
        $st = $this->pdo->query("query");
        $response ["results"] = array();

        foreach ( $st->fetchAll() as $row ) {
            //my stuff with the query
        }

        $response ["success"] = 1;
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}

$object = new Manager($conn);
```

Comment: you cant't use $this->pdo in static functions

Comment: @Frank No, you can't. But this question doesn't deal with statics and you can still use injection with static methods.

Comment: How Can I deal with $object->jsonQuery(); ? Can you put all the code of class Manager, with $conn variable  ?

Comment: @Ilovecoding I added the rest of your code into the example

Comment: It works ! It is a good choice to get access to a DB with this solution ?

Comment: I use this methodology myself in my own code base. it's easier to understand and work with because you never have to track down a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to use a function, it is allways global :-)

Simple sample:

```
function &pdo() {
  $user = 'username';
  $passowrd = 'password';
  static $db = null;
  if($db===null)
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=ip;dbname=DBName;port=3306',$user,$passowrd);
  return $db;
}
```

Alternative, but not good:
use global:

```
function foo() {
  global $conn;
  # your code ....
}
```

or

```
$GLOBALS['conn'];
```

It is allways present.

Comment: Globals are generally [something to avoid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12445972/stop-using-global-in-php)

Comment: Do you mean to put function &pdo in DB.php ?

Comment: yes, simply put the function in DB.php and use it in your code.