# How do I make an if statement which checks if a variable is in the mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $_GLOBALS['servername'] . ";dbname=". $_GLOBALS['dbname'], $_GLOBALS['username'], $_GLOBALS['password']);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM us WHERE username='$suser' and password='$shashpass'"; // SQL Query

   $conn->exec($sql);
```

Thats some of my code, how do I make it so if suser and shashpass are correct it can
execute some code, else it executes other code

This won't work either

```
    <?php 
try 
{ 
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $_GLOBALS['servername'] . ";dbname=". $_GLOBALS['dbname'], $_GLOBALS['username'], $_GLOBALS['password']); 
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
    $query = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM us WHERE username=:user and password=:password"); $query->bindParam(':user',$suser); 
    $query->bindParam(':password',$shashpass); $query->execute(); $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    if(!empty($result)){ } else { } } 
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $sql . $e->getMessage(); 
}
```

Comment: you are using `PDO` incorrectly making it vulnerable to SQL injections

Comment: How can I correct it?

Comment: pdo prepared statements http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: try as hard as you can **not** to use `$_GLOBALS` , there are some limited cases for them but as much as possible there are better ways of programming PHP now. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12445972/stop-using-global-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using `PDO` in wrong way , you need to use `prepared statements` in PDO to be secure from mysql injections, try to use the code below:

```
 try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $_GLOBALS['servername'] . ";dbname=". $_GLOBALS['dbname'], $_GLOBALS['username'], $_GLOBALS['password']);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $query = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM us WHERE username=:user and password=:password");
    $query->bindParam(':user',$suser);
    $query->bindParam(':password',$shashpass);
    $query->execute();
    $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if(!empty($result)){
     // user is in database
    } else {

    // user is not there 
    }
```

Comment: Please do not dump code in comments. Edit your original post to add any new information.

Answer (score 3):

You don't pre-hash the password when verifying it. Instead you `SELECT` the password hash from that user (if it exists) and then use [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/password_verify) to verify that it's correct based on the plain text password sent by the web form.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT password FROM us WHERE username=?");
$stmt->execute([$suser]);

if ($user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    if (password_verify($plain_text_password, $user['password'])) {
        // Successful login
    }
    else {
        // Valid user, but invalid password
    }
}
else {
    // User doesn't exist
}
```

If you're not using `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`, You're Doing It Wrong™.

Comment: You're storing the passwords in plain text? If so, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581610/how-can-i-store-my-users-passwords-safely/1581919

Comment: No, im storing it in md5, im going to switch it over to password_hash

Answer (score 0):

`exec` will return the number of affected rows so:

```
$rows = $conn->exec($sql);

if($rows > 0){
    //suser and shashpass are correct
}else{
    //suser and shashpass are incorrect
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Use below PDO code

<?php
try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=myDB", $username, $password);
// set the PDO error mode to exception
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

echo "Connected successfully"; 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM us WHERE username='$suser' and password='$shashpass'";     
// SQL Query

$conn->exec($sql);

}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```