# PHP global keyword syntax error

Tags: php

```
1.  $d = unserialize(base64_decode($params['customfields']));
2.  global $username = $d['Username'];
3.  global $password = $d['Password'];
```

I get an error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ',' or ';' in
>   line 2

whats wrong with my code? the PHP version is the latest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the variable as global

```
global $username;
global $password;
```

Then assign value for it

```
$username = $d['Username'];
$password = $d['Password'];
```

Comment: thank you very much!, accept in 7 minutes

Comment: @BlurryScript glad to help you. Please do accept :-)

Comment: Even if this is correct, I don't recommend to use global variables. It may be dangerous in big applications..

Comment: @MateiMihai whats the risk of using it? Please clarify? Also, if you dont mind on oyur profile view page `about me` section looks good. But first two lines not included in code view. I mean `class Person { protected $nam...`

Comment: Thanks for noticing me. The risk is that you may define a variable as global at some point and modify it later in the code. I don't say it creates bugs but you may spend some time to debug a wrong behavior which might be created by the usage of the global variables. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12445972/stop-using-global-in-php

Comment: @MateiMihai thanks for updating me :-) Profile seems good too :-)

Answer (score 1):

No it cant work like that you must need to make it as global variable than use it.

```
global $username;
$username = $d['Username'];
```

Answer (score 1):

`global` keyword is used to declare variable as `global`. You cannot use it with assignment operator. You can use `$GLOBALS` instead:

```
global $username,$password;
$username = $d['Username'];
$password = $d['Password'];
```

OR

```
$GLOBALS['username']= $d['Username'];
$GLOBALS['password']= $d['password'];
```

Both are appropriate methods, it's upto you what method you choose.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would use global within a function to reference a variable declared outwith the function. eg

```
$username='fred';

function blah(){
    global $username;
    echo $username;
}
```

Perhaps what you are trying to achieve should be done using the `$GLOBALS` array, eg:

```
$GLOBALS['username']=$d['username'];
```

which can then be referenced, as you would expect, pretty much anywhere eg: `echo $GLOBALS['username']`

Answer (score 0):

You should assign a value to global variable in the next line after declaring it as global.

```
$d = unserialize(base64_decode($params['customfields']));
global $username;
$username = $d['Username'];
global $password;
$password = $d['Password'];
```