# Mysqli_fetch_assoc does not work with a function

Tags: php, mysqli

If I put my code in a function it does not work. If I get rid of the function it is responding correctly. What I'm doing wrong?

```
function dayClosure() {
$qClosure = 'SELECT * FROM timeRegistration WHERE department IN ("4")';
$rClosure = mysqli_query($conn, $qClosure);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rClosure)) {
        if ($row['status'] == '3' && $row['enddate'] == '23-10-2017') {
            $totalWorkedTime += $row['worktime'];
            return $totalWorkedTime;
        }
    }
}

echo dayClosure();
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: `$conn` is not defined in the function, so PHP has no idea what it is. You need to pass it as a variable or define it as a global([Not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12445972/stop-using-global-in-php)). I suggest you make a class.

Comment: Try to pass $conn as a parameter to function. or define it as global

Comment: No error. Just blank output. If I make sure the function () { } is deleted. I get normal response from my database.

Comment: it should be a `global` variable

Comment: @PankajMakwana No, [that is not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12445972/stop-using-global-in-php).

Comment: The wierd thing is I'm loading my external database.php (require_once). Global does not help neither.

Comment: If any of the provided solution was helpful please be sure to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the function cannot access `$conn` variable, You need to provide the `$conn` variable to the function as a parameter:

```
function dayClosure($conn) {
$qClosure = 'SELECT * FROM timeRegistration WHERE department IN ("4")';
$rClosure = mysqli_query($conn, $qClosure);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rClosure)) {
        if ($row['status'] == '3' && $row['enddate'] == '23-10-2017') {
            $totalWorkedTime += $row['worktime'];
            return $totalWorkedTime;
        }
    }
}

echo dayClosure($conn);
```

Comment: The wierd thing is I'm loading my external database.php (require_once). Global does not help neither.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the function in unable to access `$conn`

The best practice is to declare this `$conn` as global.

```
global $conn;
$conn = mysqli_connect(......);
```

Another way is to pass `$conn` as function parameter:

```
function dayClosure($conn) {
```

Comment: That is certainly not the best practice. Global variables are [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12445972/stop-using-global-in-php).

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
<?php

require_once('config.php');

function dayClosure($conn) {
$qClosure = 'SELECT * FROM timeRegistration WHERE department IN ("4")';
$rClosure = mysqli_query($conn, $qClosure);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rClosure)) {
        if ($row['status'] == '3' && $row['enddate'] == '23-10-2017') {
            $totalWorkedTime += $row['worktime'];
            return $totalWorkedTime;
        }
    }
}

echo dayClosure($conn); 

?>
```

I required my file and did sent the $conn variable to the function. Thanks guys!