# Not able to get return output from PHP class

Tags: php, class

This is my code in my class

```
    <?php
class PerClass
{
    private $sql_connection = null;
    private $localAf = '9929292F';
    function __construct($env) {
        // Nasty globals, sorry
        global $_config;
    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "user";
    $pass = "pass";
    $db = "kModule";


        // Build sql connection
        $this->sql_connection = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);
        // Check connection
        if ($this->sql_connection->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $this->sql_connection->connect_error);
        }
    }

    public function getOrders($sSettingsId) {
        $query = <<<SQL
            SELECT * FROM `scrub_order_log` WHERE `scrub_settings_id` = {$sSettingsId} AND `order_date` BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL (SELECT `c_h_days` FROM `scrub_settings` WHERE `id` = {$sSettingsId}) DAY) AND NOW() ORDER BY `order_date` DESC;
SQL;
        $result = $this->sql_connection->query($query);
        $resp = null;
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $resp[] = $row;
        }
        return $resp;
    }
}
?>
```

I am trying to get the output as shown in code below

```
<?
$details = $PerClass->getOrders('1');
print_r($details);
?>
```

But unfortunately I am getting following erro

**Fatal error: Call to a member function getOrders() on null in /home/domn/public_html/stage/stage_test.php on line 37**

Tried different ways but I think I am doing something wrong

Comment: at what point do you instantiate the `$PerClass` object?

Comment: @kidA sorry for some reason the code was not displaying correct, so I edited the question again. Please see if it makes sense now.

Comment: The line that instantiates the PerClass is still missing.. Unless you forgot to add it to your code you need something like `$PerClass = new PerClass();` before the `$details = $PerClass->getOrders('1');` line.

Comment: yes when I initiate the PerClass. I get the result in array but it first line I get error

Comment: Warning: Missing argument 1 for PerClass::__construct(), called in /home/domn/public_html/stage/stage_test.php on line 37 and defined in /home/domn/public_html/stage/stage_test.php on line 6  @kidA

Comment: read the error message instead of copy-pasting it !  it tells you what the error is and how to fix it.  In your constructor, you dont need/use the ***nasty global***, nor the parameter `$env`;

Comment: do NOT use PHP short tags (`<?`). You are asking for troubles as this can be turned off in php.ini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that calls the `getOrders` method is missing the object instantiation.

```
<?
    // add this here
    $PerClass = new PerClass();
    $details = $PerClass->getOrders('1');
    print_r($details);
?>
```

now, because the constructor method of your `PerClass` expects you to pass in a value as an argument, this is going to result in the following warning:

> WARNING Missing argument 1 for PerClass::__construct()

In order to resolve this warning you have two options:

1. Pass the value of the `$env` parameter when you instantiate the object i.e. `$PerClass = new PerClass('value_to_be_passed');` or
2. Get rid of the `$env` argument in your constructor since - from what I can see - it is not used anywhere i.e. from `function __construct($env) { ... }` to `function __construct() { ... }`.

See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12445972/stop-using-global-in-php) for an interested discussion about using `global` in PHP.

Comment: Thanks alot , this was really helpful. while I was debugging at my end I found this too about getting rid of $env ,

Comment: No prob, glad I could help :)