# remove a global call inside files

Tags: php

How can remove this global.
Like you can see i have 2 globals, Is possible to remove it.
fp_new_products class call Prod class to verify is products_id exist or not.

My first files

```
  class fp_new_products {
    public function execute() {
      global $products_id;
      ....
      while ($Qproduct->fetch() ) {
        $products_id = $Qproduct->valueInt('products_id'); 
      ...  
      }
  }
```

my second file

```
    class Prod {
        public function getID() {
          if (isset($_GET['products_id']) && is_numeric($_GET['products_id']) && !empty(HTML::sanitize($_GET['products_id']))) {
            $this->Id = HTML::sanitize($_GET['products_id']);
          } else {
            $this->Id = null;
          }
-- listing    
          if (is_null($this->Id) ) {
            if (isset($_GET['products_id']) && is_numeric($_POST['products_id']) && !empty(HTML::sanitize($_POST['products_id']))) {
              $this->Id = HTML::sanitize($_POST['products_id']);
            } else {


              global $products_id;
              $this->Id = HTML::sanitize($products_id);


            }
          }

          return $this->Id;
        }
```

result

```
    public function getID() {
// get products_id
      $this->Id  = empty($_GET['products_id']) ? null : HTML::sanitize($_GET['products_id']);

//products_listing
      if (is_null($this->Id) ) {
        if (isset($_GET['products_id']) && is_numeric($_POST['products_id']) && !empty(HTML::sanitize($_POST['products_id']))) {
          $this->Id = HTML::sanitize($_POST['products_id']);
        } else {
          $this->Id = empty($_POST['products_id']) ? null : HTML::sanitize($_POST['products_id']);
        }
      }

      return $this->Id;
    }
```

Comment: remove? unset()? comment out?

Comment: FWIW: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12445972/stop-using-global-in-php  Basically suggest reading up on [PHP OOP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php).

Comment: Pass the data by dependency injection,  `public function execute($product_id)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple things,

You should be using dependency injection, whenever creating classes.  That is just a fancy way of saying pass any data into the class as arguments.

The reason can be illustrated with this one.

```
public function getID() {
  if (isset($_GET['products_id']) && is_numeric($_GET['products_id']) && !empty(HTML::sanitize($_GET['products_id']))) {
    $this->Id = HTML::sanitize($_GET['products_id']);
  } else {
    $this->Id = null;
  }
...
}
```

The problem here is this method can only be used if you have a Query string in the url with `products_id` in it.  Which means you cannot reuse this code unless the "dependency" is met.

Instead of that do this:

```
public function getID($product_id=null) {
   if($product_id){
         $this->Id = HTML::sanitize($product_id);
   }else{
         $this->Id = null;
   }
 ...
}
```

When you call this method check The get variable

```
 $product_id = empty($_GET['products_id']) ? null : $_GET['products_id'];
 $obj->getID($product_id);
```

Now if you happen to have a product ID you want to use from some where else, maybe it's `$_POST` you can reuse this code.

```
 $product_id = empty($_POST['products_id']) ? null : $_POST['products_id'];
 $obj->getID($product_id);
```

No issue.

The same holds true for `global`.  Instead of depending on it existing, pass the data in.

```
  class fp_new_products {
    public function execute($products_id) {
      ....
      while ($Qproduct->fetch() ) {
        $products_id = $Qproduct->valueInt('products_id'); 
      ...  
      }
  }
```

And then when you call

```
 $obj->execute($products_id);
```

This way your classes don't care where the data comes from, it could be a global, POST, GET or whatever and your code is still usable.

In fact you should not depend on any of those things within a class.

Now if you are changing the value (it looks like you are), you have 2 choices. You can return it and set it:

```
 public function execute($products_id) {
      ....
      while ($Qproduct->fetch() ) {
        //this makes no sense by the way...
        $products_id = $Qproduct->valueInt('products_id'); 
      ...  
      }
      return $products_id; //return the results
  }

 $products_id = $obj->execute($products_id);
```

Or you can pass by reference with the `&`

```
public function execute(&$products_id) {
      ....
      while ($Qproduct->fetch() ) {
        //this makes no sense by the way...
        $products_id = $Qproduct->valueInt('products_id'); 
      ...  
      }
  }

 $obj->execute($products_id);
```

And it will be "magically" updated.

Lastly as I said this:

```
  //this makes no sense by the way...
   $products_id = $Qproduct->valueInt('products_id');
```

If you look at it, that loop will overwrite this value on each iteration. Which really is probably not what you want.

One thing that may help you a lot is this [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) principles. Either that or it will just confuse you more ... lol.  Basically it has to do with changing how you think of classes, they should have a single responsibility and should be a "Black Box", the outside world shouldn't care what they do, and they shouldn't care about the outside world.

For example (using the first one). The method `getID` shouldn't care that that data came from `$_GET`.

Hope that helps.

**UPDATE**

Just to clarify this:

```
class Prod {
    public function getID() {
      if (isset($_GET['products_id']) && is_numeric($_GET['products_id']) && !empty(HTML::sanitize($_GET['products_id']))) {
        $this->Id = HTML::sanitize($_GET['products_id']);
      } else {
        $this->Id = null;
      }
-- listing    
      if (is_null($this->Id) ) {
        if (isset($_GET['products_id']) && is_numeric($_POST['products_id']) && !empty(HTML::sanitize($_POST['products_id']))) {
          $this->Id = HTML::sanitize($_POST['products_id']);
        } else {


          global $products_id;
          $this->Id = HTML::sanitize($products_id);


        }
      }

      return $this->Id;
    }
```

Can be done this way:

```
class Prod {
    public function getID($products_id=null) {
      if ($products_id) {
        $this->Id = HTML::sanitize($products_id);
      } else {
        $this->Id = null;
      }
-- listing    
      return $this->Id;
    }
```

See how much smaller it is.  Because the class doesn't need to care about `$_GET` vs `$_POST`.  But when you call this you will check those.

```
$obj->getID((empty($_GET['products_id'])?null:$_GET['products_id']));
```

Which is basically like saying this

```
if(empty($_GET['products_id']))
    $products_id = null;
else
    $products_id = $_GET['products_id'];

$obj->getID($products_id);
```

You should know when you make the call rather you are dealing with `$_GET` or `$_POST`.

You can probably simplify this further, if you only pass in Integers or Null

```
class Prod {
   public function getID($products_id=null) {
      $this->Id = $products_id ? $products_id : null;
-- listing    
      return $this->Id;
   }


$obj->getID((int)$products_id); //instead of is_numeric
```

But this is starting to get to the Classroom stage, instead of the simple answer stage.

Comment: Tk for you explanation, great. You say : If you look at it, that loop will overwrite this value on each iteration. Which really is probably not what you want
No, I display different products with different id. 8 products, 8 id

Comment: Right, but because its `global $products_id;` in your code, your changing it on each iteration, and at the end you will be left with whatever was the last one set in the loop.  So if you use it as a global outside of this class after running that, it's going to have whatever that last one was (probably, I never use global).

Comment: Just info, my pb is on --listing comment. Sorry I don't explain that. It help me lot of

Comment: It also may not be obvious where that happened at, which is why globals are frowned upon.  They can be exceptionally hard to debug, errors like that can take days to figure out.

Comment: Could you look if it's correct like this (see Result above) ? tk