# Access PHP object from inside a function

Tags: php, class, oop, object

I have created a PHP class and I want to access its methods from a function in another file. Below is my code:

```
include_once PLUGIN_DIR_PATH."/classes/Brands.php";

function create_tables(){

$brand_obj = new Brands;    
$brand_obj->create_brand_table();           
}

function delete_tables() {

$brand_obj = new Brands;    
$brand_obj->delete_brand_table();
}
```

Is it possible to create the object only once and then reuse it in every function? Right now, I am creating object in every function which is not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the global keyword to use a variable created outside a function inside a function:

```
global $object
```

code example :

```
include_once PLUGIN_DIR_PATH."/classes/Brands.php";

$brand_obj = new Brands;

function create_tables(){

    global $brand_obj;
    $brand_obj->create_brand_table();
}

function delete_tables() {

   global $brand_obj;
   $brand_obj->delete_brand_table();
}
```

Comment: Using global variables should be avoided whenever possible. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12446305/965834) for details.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume your actual functions do more than what you posted, otherwise you don't really need functions and can simply do this:

```
$brand_obj = new Brands;    
$brand_obj->create_brand_table();            
$brand_obj->delete_brand_table();
```

Otherwise, you can make a class and inject the `Brands` dependency into one of its properties via its constructor:

```
class TablesManager
{
  private $brands;

  public function __construct(Brands $brands)
  {
    $this->brands = $brands;
  }

  public function create_tables(): void
  {
    $this->brands->create_brand_table();
  }

  public function delete_tables(): void
  {
    $this->brands->delete_brand_table();
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
$brands = new Brands();
$tables_manager = new TablesManager($brands);
$tables_manager->create_tables();
$tables_manager->delete_tables();
```

Note: calling a class `SomethingManager` is sometimes considered bad practice / a sign that the class does too many things. Consider (at least) giving it a more accurate name for your needs.

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/iTmY6**

### Non-OOP alternative

```
function create_tables(Brands $brand_obj): void { 
  $brand_obj->create_brand_table();           
}

function delete_tables(Brands $brand_obj): void {
  $brand_obj->delete_brand_table();
}

$brand_obj = new Brands();    
create_tables($brand_obj);
delete_tables($brand_obj);
```