# Update SQL table by prepare binding parameters in PHP using a Common Function

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I work on making a common function in PHP to update table because I have a lot of forms update MySQL tables. It is working fine and it update my table: below is my code with some comments:

```
<?php
include('../config.php');
if (isset($_POST['loginfo'])) {
    $table = "users";
    $creteria = "id =?";
    if (update_table($table,$creteria)){
        echo "<h1> Successfully Updated Table: ". $table. "</h1>";
    }   
}           
        
function update_table($tablename,$creteria) {
    $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    $sql = "UPDATE ".$tablename. " SET ";                                                   
    $postdata = $_POST;
    $count = count($postdata);  
    $nonempty = count(array_filter($postdata, function($x) { return ($x !== ""); }));
    $i = 0;                                                                                 
    $vartype = "";
    foreach ($postdata as $key => $value) { 
        $i++;
        if (!empty($value)) {
            $nonempty--;
            $sql .= " $key = ? ";
            if ($nonempty >0) {
                $sql .= " ,";
            }           
            if(is_int($value)){
                $vartype .= "i";
            } else {
                $vartype .= "s";
            }
        }            
    }   
    $sql .= "WHERE ".$creteria;
    $vartype .= "i";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $params = array(&$fullname, &$email, &$phone, &$id);// this line must be out side function
    call_user_func_array(array($stmt, "bind_param"), array_merge(array($vartype), $params));    
        $fullname = $_POST['fullname']; // fullname,email,phone, id must be out of function
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
        $conn->close();
        return true;    
}
?>
```

How to put $params array, out side function? So I can pass different parameters regarding submitted form?

Comment: You can add another parameter in `update_table($tablename,$creteria,$params)` What's wrong with that?

Comment: @Dharman actually, there is so much wrong. $params is just a tip of the iceberg. Variables below are hardcoded, making the whole struggle in vain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrite your function,and is working fine for me, you can check this. In your code criteria is still SQLIA vulnerable. Thus, following is the
equivalent code update any table with condition as follows-

```
function update_table(string $tablename,array $criteria, array $updateData) {
    $params = array_merge(array_values($updateData), array_values(reset($criteria)));
    try {
        $conn = new PDO(sprintf('mysql:dbname=%s;host=%s', DB_DATABASE, DB_HOSTNAME), 
                            DB_USERNAME, 
                            DB_PASSWORD);
        $updateLastKey = array_key_last($updateData);        
        $sql = sprintf("UPDATE %s SET ", $tablename);
        
        foreach($updateData as $key => $item) {
           $sql = sprintf("%s %s = ?%s ", $sql, $key,$key == $updateLastKey? "" : "," );
        }
        
        $sql = sprintf("%s WHERE %s", $sql, key($criteria));
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($params);
        $conn = null;
    } catch (PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
    }

    return true;    
}
```

Now you can call above function as follows-

```
 $updateData = ["name"=>$_POST['name'], "price"=> $_POST['price']];
 $criteria = ["category_id = ? and price>=?  " => [1, 500]];
 update_table('products',$criteria,$updateData);
// this will update all the products whose category id is 1 and price is greater than 500
```

Note : **I think using PDO is better than mysqli**

Comment: `foreach($updateData as $key => $key)` What is this?

Comment: PDO is indeed better but this function is still wrong on many levels. there must be no  new PDO, no die($e->getMessage()), no $databaseName

Comment: What is more important, thus function is rather useless. the same can be done with less code being **100 times easier to read**, `prepared_query($db, "UPDATE products SET name=?, price=? WHERE category_id = ? and price>=?", [$_POST['name'],$_POST['price'],1,500]);` where prepared_query being 10 times shorter and more universal.

Comment: @YourCommonSense agree with you. This is in case somebody donot want to see the raw query most of the time. In your way code is also more efficient because there is no further processing regarding the mapping.

Comment: @VeshrajJoshi, your code is work with me for all forms and tables. as I'm newer in PHP I don't know why some developers tell you your way is not good. but can you do fever to modify function as per their suggestion?

Answer (score -1):

You can use params variable as global. And you can merge or directly to equal them with interval variable, inside function.For example:

```php
$paramsGlobal = ['name'=> 'Tural Rza'];

function update_table($tablename,$creteria) {
    global $paramsGlobal;
    $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    $sql = "UPDATE ".$tablename. " SET ";                                                   
    $postdata = $_POST;
    $count = count($postdata);  
    $nonempty = count(array_filter($postdata, function($x) { return ($x !== ""); }));
    $i = 0;                                                                                 
    $vartype = "";
    foreach ($postdata as $key => $value) { 
        $i++;
        if (!empty($value)) {
            $nonempty--;
            $sql .= " $key = ? ";
            if ($nonempty >0) {
                $sql .= " ,";
            }           
            if(is_int($value)){
                $vartype .= "i";
            } else {
                $vartype .= "s";
            }
        }            
    }   
    $sql .= "WHERE ".$creteria;
    $vartype .= "i";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $params = array_merge(array(&$fullname, &$email, &$phone, &$id),$paramsGlobal);// this line must be out side function
    call_user_func_array(array($stmt, "bind_param"), array_merge(array($vartype), $params));    
        $fullname = $_POST['fullname']; // fullname,email,phone, id must be out of function
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
        $conn->close();
        return true;    
}
?>
```

Comment: You shouldn't use global like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/12446305/285587

Comment: Besides, your code doesn't solve the actual problem